# Hadoop Jobtracker web homepage not accessible

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I just installed jobtracker and task trackers but as soon as I start any of my tasktrackers 
Job trackers homepage gives following error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.digitsRoundedUp()Z
    at java.text.DigitList.set(DigitList.java:292)
    at java.text.DecimalFormat.format(DecimalFormat.java:599)
    at java.text.DecimalFormat.format(DecimalFormat.java:522)
    at java.text.NumberFormat.format(NumberFormat.java:271)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.jobtracker_jsp.generateSummaryTable(jobtracker_jsp.java:26)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.jobtracker_jsp._jspService(jobtracker_jsp.java:146)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:98)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1221)
    at org.apache.hadoop.http.lib.StaticUserWebFilter$StaticUserFilter.doFilter(StaticUserWebFilter.java:109)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1212)
    at org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer$QuotingInputFilter.doFilter(HttpServer.java:1069)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1212)
    at org.apache.hadoop.http.NoCacheFilter.doFilter(NoCacheFilter.java:45)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1212)
    at org.apache.hadoop.http.NoCacheFilter.doFilter(NoCacheFilter.java:45)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1212)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:399)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:766)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:450)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:230)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:928)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:549)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:212)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:410)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
```

Whereas in jobtracker::50030/machines.jsp?type=active all tasktrackers are showed in running state.

**Hadoop Version:**  Hadoop 2.0.0-cdh4.6.0 and **java version**:   "1.7.0_55"

My jobtracker/tasktracker everything is working fine but I am unable to access jobtracker's web homepage. Similarly in hbase I am getting this exception on every command run, but hbase is working fine.

*hbase(main):003:0> list
TABLE

t1

Java::JavaLang::NoSuchMethodError: sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.digitsRoundedUp()Z*
Any suggestions please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed this issue actually **while installing java I downloaded floatingdecimal.jar** manually from [maven repository](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/io/airlift/floatingdecimal/0.1/floatingdecimal-0.1.jar) which was causing issue. After deleting jar not only jobtracker issue is resolved but also hbase exception is removed.